# Force sending DHCP options

Tags: dhcp, fedora, pxe-boot, dhcp-server, tftp

I have a lab spectrometer that boots using PXE from boot files stored on a computer. They exist inside a local network with the computer acting as both the DHCP and TFTP server.

The spectrometer contains three components, two boot fine and one is probelmatic. It requires that boot-size option is given. However, it does not request DHCP options and subsequently does not get them. Is there any way to force them to be sent, even if not requested.

I am using a modern Fedora 36 computer with dhcpd, however the spectrometer is 20+ years old. Our old lab computer used PXE-dhcp, however I couldn't find a version that would run on a modern OS.

This is my dhcpd.conf file:

```
allow booting;
allow bootp;
get-lease-hostnames   true;

option tftp-server-name "192.168.1.1";
ddns-update-style none;
subnet 192.168.1.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
        range 192.168.1.1 192.168.1.250;
}
#
# individual hosts
#
host wbandspc { filename "/usr/xepr/AcquisitionServer/OS9/CPU/P4X/BOOTP_16MB/os9boot";
        hardware ethernet 00:40:98:00:00:75; option root-path "192.168.1.1:/usr/xepr/AcquistionServer/OS9";
        fixed-address 192.168.1.10; option boot-size 1396;}
```

Any help wpuld be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not mind using an all-in-one Windows application (DHCP, proxyDHCP, TFTP, HTTP, etc.) then you can do what you want with [Serva](https://www.vercot.com/%7Eserva/default.html).